# How to declare 3 dimensions string array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>

char count[3][5][14]={{"♠1","♠2","♠3","♠4","♠5","♠6","♠7","♠8","♠9","♠10","♠J","♠Q","♠K"},
                            {"◇1","◇2","◇3","◇4","◇5","◇6","◇7","◇8","◇9","◇10","◇J","◇Q","◇K"},
                            {"♣1","♣2","♣3","♣4","♣5","♣6","♣7","♣8","♣9","♣10","♣J","♣Q","♣K"},
                            {"♡1","♡2","♡3","♡4","♡5","♡6","♡7","♡8","♡9","♡10","♡J","♡Q","♡K"};
```

I want to declare this type of array but it always makes errors such as"Too many initializers". How can I fix this error?

Comment: You declare a 3 dimensions array. For first dimension, you have written 3, but give 4 elements, so yes, too many initializers. And you use c++, so use containers (like std::vector) instead of raw array

Comment: I think perhaps you expect index [3] to correspond to the 3 characters in your "♠1"?
If so the array declaration order is wrong, should be 
char count[5][14][3]

Comment: That is a `[4][13][3]` array.

Comment: I think you want a `std::string count[4][13]` 2D array instead.

Comment: @Ron 1 and aces aren't same ? (I'm not an cards player)

Comment: That's a 3d char array or 2d string array, that you are asking for, not a 3d string array.

Comment: @Ron it depends if he want to store string inside array or just store pointer to a string

Comment: @Garf365 I see.

Comment: Also note that the card signs are Unicode, and might be more than 1 byte.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is maybe this:

```
const char * count[4][13]= {{"♠1","♠2","♠3","♠4","♠5","♠6","♠7","♠8","♠9","♠10","♠J","♠Q","♠K"},
                            {"◇1","◇2","◇3","◇4","◇5","◇6","◇7","◇8","◇9","◇10","◇J","◇Q","◇K"},
                            {"♣1","♣2","♣3","♣4","♣5","♣6","♣7","♣8","♣9","♣10","♣J","♣Q","♣K"},
                            {"♡1","♡2","♡3","♡4","♡5","♡6","♡7","♡8","♡9","♡10","♡J","♡Q","♡K"}};
```

Anyway as already suggested `std::vector` and `std::string` should be preferred

Comment: You store a pointer to constant string, please, use at least  `const char *`, or `const char * const`

Comment: @Garf365 approved :)

Answer (score 2):

The C++ way would be using a string class like `std::string` and a container like `std::vector` (not raw C-style `char` strings and raw arrays), e.g.:

```
 vector<vector<vector<string>>> x;
```

If what you really want is a two-dimension string array, then that would be:

```
 vector<vector<string>> x;
```

Comment: Excellent answer, probably not one expected (see molbdnilo comment) but, actually the best IMHO

Comment: Seems more likely that the OP is asking to learn rather than to do the best application, so IMHO it is better to give him the array solution 1st, and suggest the vector solution 2nd.